# add number and operators to array PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to add a row of numbers and operators to an array. How can i do it correctly?

What I wish is to separate each number group to one index and in the next index operator .

I need your help to show me where is the error in my code:

```
function toArray($s){

    $le = strlen($s);
    $j = 0;
    $ordered_numbers_operators = array();
    $operators = array('+','-','*','/','%','(',')');

    for ( $i=0;$i<$le;$i++ ){

        if ( in_array( $s[$i], $operators )  ) {
            $ordered_numbers_operators[$j] = $s[$i];
            $j++;

        } else {

            if ( $i+1 == $le ){
                $ordered_numbers_operators[$j] = $s[$i];

            } else {

                if ( $s[$i+1] !== in_array( $s[$i+1], $operators ))  {

                    if ( $s[$i+1] == in_array( $s[$i+1], $operators )){
                        echo "\$i = " . $i . "<br />" ;
                        $ordered_numbers_operators[$j]=$s[$i];
                        $j++;

                    } else {

                        $ordered_numbers_operators[$j] = $s[$i] . $s[$i+1];
                        $i++; $j++;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $ordered_numbers_operators;

    }

$string = '6+4*4+100+444*6*13*14';

$arr = toArray($string);
```

The expected result:

```
[0] => 6
[1] => +
[2] => 4
[3] => *
[4] => 4
[5] => +
[6] => 100
[7] => +  
[8] => 444  
[9] => *
[10] => 6
[11] => *
[12] => 13
[13] => *
[14] => 14
```

The actual result:

```
[0] => 6
[1] => +
[2] => 4
[3] => *
[4] => 4
[5] => +
[6] => 1
[7] => 0
[8] => 0
[9] => +
[10] => 44
[11] => 4
[12] => *
[13] => 6
[14] => *
[15] => 13
[16] => *
[17] => 14
```

Comment: @chris85 add it as an answer ;) But personally speaking ... sometimes... I just wanna use 30 lines of code that are not regex based lol :D

Comment: @chris85 His code include operators that can include `%`, `(`, or `)`

Comment: @FrankerZ Those can be added to the character class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without regex, you can do this a lot more simply. See [this example, to test and run](https://3v4l.org/mDEPu):

```
<?php


function toArray($s){
    $operators = array('+','-','*','/','%','(',')');

    $finalArr = [];
    $curStr = '';
    foreach (str_split($s) as $char) {
        if (in_array($char, $operators)) {
            //Alright, we have an operator. Append the entire number
            $finalArr[] = $curStr;
            //And also the operator
            $finalArr[] = $char;
            //Reset the current string back to empty
            $curStr = '';
        } else {
            //Not an operator? Just keep appending the current number
            $curStr .= $char;
        }
    }

    //Add final leftover string
    if ($curStr !== '') { //Sanity check here (This shouldn't ever be empty, as you wouldn't end with an operator)
        $finalArr[] = $curStr;
    }

    //Return
    return $finalArr;
}

$string = '6+4*4+100+444*6*13*14';

$arr = toArray($string);

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I think its valid if you hate regex. Plus it opens a lot of spots where more tweaking and customizing can happen.

Comment: thank you @FrankerZ, is there any other way without using str_split() ?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with a regex and `preg_split`, a bit easier.

```
$parts = preg_split('~([+*/-])~', '6+4*4+100+444*6*13*14', -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($parts);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/oCrLG

Note the `-` as the last character in the character class is important. If you add more characters after that the `-` will create a range between the closest character on each side. Any characters you want to separate on can be added inside the `[]`. If adding `]` though be sure to escape it so the closure is correct. You can read more about character classes here, https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html.

The character class also makes it so you don't need to escape special regex characters. You could also do it like this, which removes the character class.

```
$parts = preg_split('~(\+|\*|/|-)~', '6+4*4+100+444*6*13*14', -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($parts);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/Jha6P

Additionally whitespace can be made optional with `\s*` or `\h*` before and after the operators.

```
$parts = preg_split('~\h*([+*/-])\h*~', '6+4*4+100+444*6*13*14', -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($parts);
```

Comment: Nice answer! `preg_split` is definitely the way to go if regex doesn't haunt you in your dreams.

Comment: It haunts me in my dreams... but also my propensity to do things in 'one line of code' is at odds with those nightmares ;) So I upvote both solutions, because they both are great!

Comment: @IncredibleHat Thanks, yea I saw nothing wrong with the other solution, just a different approach (hopefully your dreams will subside)

Comment: Diversity is good... I like finding questions with vastly different valid solutions, because it helps one learn of the possibilities to solve a problem.

Comment: I like this solution! With `'~\s*([+*/-])\s*~'` the input can even contain whitespace, e.g. `'6 + 4 * 4 + 100'`. Cool.

Comment: Good idea, I'll add that when at a computer

Comment: thank you @chris85 but i want to do it without regex.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Haha, not yet this year, just kinda going a different direction from SO. I'll be around just less frequently

Comment: @chris85 I am also less active now myself. You take care of yourself and enjoy the ride ;-) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Another regex-free way is to use `array_reduce`.

You can use `str_split` to split the string into an array, and then use `array_reduce` to build your desired array (so that consecutive numbers are joined). Let's do that step by step. First, with a simple callback function in `array_reduce`, we get the same result as with `str_split`:

```
function toArray($string) {
    $chars = str_split($string);

    return array_reduce($chars, function($result, $current) {
        $result[] = $current;

        return $result;
    }, []);
}

$input = '6+4*4+100+444*6*13*14';
print_r(toArray($input));

/*
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => +
    [2] => 4
    [3] => *
    [4] => 4
    [5] => +
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [9] => +
    [10] => 4
    [11] => 4
    [12] => 4
    [13] => *
    [14] => 6
    [15] => *
    [16] => 1
    [17] => 3
    [18] => *
    [19] => 1
    [20] => 4
)
*/
```

Next step is to check the previous value and the current value when iterating over the characters in `array_reduce`. If they are both numbers, we want to join them:

```
function toArray($string) {
    $chars = str_split($string);

    return array_reduce($chars, function($result, $current) {
        $previous = $result[] = array_pop($result);

        if (is_numeric($previous) && is_numeric($current)) {
            $result[] = array_pop($result) . $current;
        } else {
            $result[] = $current;
        }

        return $result;
    }, []);
}

$input = '6+4*4+100+444*6*13*14';
print_r(toArray($input));

/*
Array
(
    [0] =>
    [1] => 6
    [2] => +
    [3] => 4
    [4] => *
    [5] => 4
    [6] => +
    [7] => 100
    [8] => +
    [9] => 444
    [10] => *
    [11] => 6
    [12] => *
    [13] => 13
    [14] => *
    [15] => 14
)
*/
```

Almost there! The array contains one extra element at index zero. (That's because we are getting the previous item with `$previous = $result[] = array_pop($result);`. Its value is `null`, because initially `$result` is an empty array, so `array_pop` returns `null`.) We can get rid of the extra element e.g. with `array_slice`:

```
function toArray($string) {
    $chars = str_split($string);

    $array = array_reduce($chars, function($result, $current) {
        $previous = $result[] = array_pop($result);

        if (is_numeric($previous) && is_numeric($current)) {
            $result[] = array_pop($result) . $current;
        } else {
            $result[] = $current;
        }

        return $result;
    }, []);

    return array_slice($array, 1);
}

$input = '6+4*4+100+444*6*13*14';
print_r(toArray($input));

/*
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => +
    [2] => 4
    [3] => *
    [4] => 4
    [5] => +
    [6] => 100
    [7] => +
    [8] => 444
    [9] => *
    [10] => 6
    [11] => *
    [12] => 13
    [13] => *
    [14] => 14
)
*/
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/qZsvs

Comment: Welcome to the team. Innovative solution